# Using jQuery to insert html to a button value?

Tags: jquery, submit

I have a button that I want to change the value of from 'Search' to a font awesome icon. I don't have access to the html code so have used Jquery to change the text as below -

```
document.getElementById("gmw-submit-1").value = "Search";
```

However, I can't put html into the value box, only plain text. I want to put the code below in instead of he word 'search'. How can I go about this?

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

Comment: Why would you want to put html in the value attribute/property? I think that would be an anti pattern

Comment: document.getElementById("gmw-submit-1").innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-search></i>'"

Comment: So I can insert the Font awesome icon rather than plain text?

Comment: what is wrong with  $.css('font-style', 'italic');?

Comment: Sorry why the css reference?

Answer (score 1):

If the button is a input type submit you can't put html in its value atribute, if its a button element than you can append html to it